PyCharm Error: 'JAVA_HOME does not point to a valid JVM installation' after working fine for a month
I've been using PyCharm without any issues for over a month. However, starting yesterday, I encountered the following error when trying to open the Python packages section:

Error launching PyCharm No JVM installation found. Please install a
JDK. If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable
in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment
Variables.

To resolve this, I installed JDK 1.8 and JRE 1.8.0_421, and set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-1.8. Now, I'm getting a different error:

Error launching PyCharm The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the
value of C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-1.8) does not point to a
valid JVM installation.

Error Images for reference:

Image -2 (After installing JDK and setting the Environment variable of JAVA_HOME)


Installed JDK 1.8 and JRE 1.8.0_421.
Set JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-1.8.
Verified that the path exists and points to the JDK directory.

I want to continue using PyCharm without encountering these JVM-related errors.

It seems like PyCharm is using Java 17, not Java 8. How are you running it?

I'm launching PyCharm directly from the desktop shortcut on my Windows machine. I initially received the error related to the JVM, which prompted me to install Java 8

I reinstalled PyCharm which seems to work now.
